# Linux + how to run the ssh-keygen interactive from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh-keys, public-key, expect

Please advice how to generate the file **id_rsa.pub** without answering the questions from "**ssh-keygen -t rsa**"

my target is to run the ssh-keygen from bash script from **postgress USER**, and it must run interactive ,  or maybe run the id_rsa.pub with different syntax ?

Example - this approach ins"t interactive :

```
 su - postgres -c "ssh-keygen -t rsa"
 Generating public/private rsa key pair.
 Enter file in which to save the key (/var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/id_rsa):
 Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
 Enter same passphrase again:
 Your identification has been saved in /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/id_rsa.
 Your public key has been saved in /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
 The key fingerprint is:
 a5:c8:fb:ff:fa:3b:55:59:9c:90:4e:28:35:f0:46:7c 
 The key's randomart image is:
 +--[ RSA 2048]----+
 |         .++..o..|
 |         .oo.E .o|
 |          oo+   o|
 |     . . o.  . ..|
 |      o S      . |
 |       .      .  |
 |      .      .   |
 |       .    .    |
 |        ..o++o   |
 +-----------------+



 # ls
 authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

I already try the following by EOF loop in order to answers the ssh-keygen interactive but without success

```
# su - postgres -c "ssh-keygen -t rsa
>
>
> <<<EOF"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is the working answer to create the public key from postgresql user

```
   su - postgres -c " cat /dev/zero | ssh-keygen -q -N \"\" "
```

Comment: can you explain please why my answer get (-1) , this command is working !

Answer (score 0):

Try `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa -P ''`

The `-f` flag will specify the file location and the `-P` flag will specify the passphrase (empty in this case).

Comment: when I ran the su - postgres -c "  ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa -P '' " , its create the public key on root in place on user postgresql

Comment: Try `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/id_rsa -P ''`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the passphrase with the -N argument

```
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "passphrase"
```

Comment: su - postgres -c " ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "passphrase" " , its still ask questions